# xslt checkbox not working and onclick event malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, xslt

The main purpose is to generate an HTML checkbox from XSLT. I used two images, one checked and the other one unchecked to come up with a solution. Now the problem is when I am clicking any checkbox the image gets changed, it's not being specific.

// this is the sample xslt file

```
   <label>
                <xsl:element name="a">
                    <xsl:attribute name="title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dispval"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$check_url"></xsl:value-of> 
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dispval_abbr"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dispcount"/> 
                </xsl:element>

                   <!--   <xsl:attribute name="src">{$resource_path_prefix}images/<xsl:value-of select='blankbox.jpg'/></xsl:attribute>-->
                 <xsl:variable name="addresource" select="concat($resource_path_prefix,'images/blankbox.png')"/>              
                      <img>
                      <xsl:attribute name="src">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$addresource"/>
                      </xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:attribute name="size">12</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:attribute name="height">12</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:attribute name="id">imgClickAndChange</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">javascript:changeImage()</xsl:attribute>
                      </img>  

            </label>
```

//this is the javascript function

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

<![CDATA[
    function changeImage() {


       if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src =="http://localhost:8000/V3/V3.07.9.9/images/blankbox.png")

        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "http://localhost:8000/V3/V3.07.9.9/images/tickbox.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src ="http://localhost:8000/V3/V3.07.9.9/images/blankbox.png";
        }
    } 
]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you being so verbose? You could write that img tag as `<img src="{$addresource}" size="12" height="12" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="javascript:changeImage()"/>`.

Comment: @MichaelKay thats fine but still whenever I am clicking on any checkbox only the first one is geting effected,others remain unaffected! please solve that part.

Comment: This is a Javascript/HTML problem, not an XSLT problem (which is why I'm not likely to be much help in solving it). If you look at the HTML that the XSLT generates, the problem may become obvious: but at the moment you're showing us only a small part of the total picture, and I suspect it's not the part where your bug is.